# How would I find the nearest space per every 2000 characters and add everything before it to a variable? (Python)

Tags: python

I'm currently writing a program that posts messages with a 2,000 character limit. The string I'm using is usually around 10,000 characters. However, the method I'm using to divide it up can divide the string up in the middle of a word - how would I only have it divide at the nearest space (BEFORE) 2k characters?

Here's the current code:

```
text = str(post.selftext)
title = await client.send_message(message.author, str(post.title))
if len(text) > 1990:
    amountsplit = math.ceil(len(text) / 1990)
    atatime = math.floor(len(text) / amountsplit)
    donetimes = 0
    lastone = 0
    for i in range(amountsplit):
        todonow = int(donetimes + 1) * atatime
        tmp = await client.send_message(message.author, str(text[lastone:todonow]))
        lastone = todonow
        donetimes += 1
```

Comment: Do you know that the `index` and `find` methods of string also have two extra arguments that specify the start and end index for the search? Also there exist the `rfind`/`rindex` versions which find the *rightmost* occurrence. For example: `>>> 'abc def gh jk'.rfind(' ', 0, 8) --> 7`. But keep in mind: there *could* be no space!

Comment: @Bakuriu From what I plan to use it with, I'm fairly certain there will definitely be a space somewhere before the character limit. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U can use `rfind()` method of `str`:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def split_message(message, character_limit=2000):
    messages = []

    while len(message) > character_limit:
        split_index = message[:character_limit].rfind(" ")
        if split_index == -1:
            # No space found, just split at the character limit
            split_index = character_limit
        else:
            # Else space is found, split after the space
            split_index += 1
        messages.append(message[:split_index])
        message = message[split_index:] 
    messages.append(message)
    return messages

# Test code 
test_string = "this  is a test string to see if this works right"
test_string = "thisisateststringwithnospaces"

for character_limit in range(1, 10):
    print ("limit", character_limit, ": ", split_message(test_string, character_limit))
```

Comment: You've given me some great ideas! Just wanted to note I'm using python 3.6.0 so no need for the print function import ;)

Comment: Great advice - works perfectly even with asyncio and a little bit of fine-tuning! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can take the characters and read it from the end (with a decremental loop `for` until find space) It should look like :

```
for i in range(len(text)-1, 0, -1):
    if text[i]==' ':
            break
            print "found the last space !"
```

**EDIT**

```
VeryLongText="the very long text..[..]....here"
text = VeryLongText[0:1999]

for i in range(len(text)-1, 0, -1):
     if text[i]==' ':
            Var=text[0:i]
            break
print Var
```

`Var` will be your `text` (the first 2000 characters of the long text) until the last space

Comment: I like your answer, but how would I add everything before it to a variable - how would I find the space's position in the string?

Comment: you will get the value of "i" of the last space then to put your text from the beginning to the last space, in the variable do `Var=text[0:i]`

Answer (score 0):

Use a generator.

```py
def messages_from_post(post, limit=2000):
    while len(post) > limit:
        try:
            i = post.rindex(' ', 0, limit + 1)
        except ValueError:
            i = limit
        message, post = map(str.lstrip, [post[:i], post[i:]])
        yield message
    yield post
```